# how to restream to nginx then save recording 1 minute then forward

Tags: nginx, rtmp

please help

i have problem in configuration nginx.conf for rtmp.

I want when I want to stream to https://ip/live/streaming then save the stream for 1 minute then push it to rtmp youtube but I always fail in configuration.

I searched the internet and my documentation couldn't find saving the video for 1 minute and then forwarding it and pushing it to YouTube's rtmp.

please nginx and the community here help me.
script in nginx.conf

```
load_module modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;

        application live {
            live on;
    push rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxx

        }
    }
}
```